# showing a search result using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax to display the result of my search but it is not working and I cannot find out why. Here is my .html file that contain Ajax too.

**JS**

```
function showSearchResult() {
    alert('beginning');
    if (document.getElementById("search").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    try {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    // handle old browsers
    if (xhr == null) {
        alert("Ajax not supported by your browser!");
        return;
    }
    var string = document.getElementById("search").value;       
    var url = "quote4.php?search=" + string;


    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function handler() {

    // only handle loaded requests
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

        else alert("Error with Ajax call!");
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Live Search</h1>

<form>
    <input id="search" size="100" type="search"> <input id="submit"
    onclick="showSearchResult(); return false;" type="button" value="Go">
</form>

<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
// pretend server is slow


// try to get quote
$handle = @fopen("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={$_GET['search']}&f=e1l1hg", "r");
if ($handle !== FALSE)
{
    $data = fgetcsv($handle);
    if ($data !== FALSE && $data[0] == "N/A")
    {
        print("Price: {$data[1]}");
        print("<br />");
        print("High: {$data[2]}");
        print("<br />");
        print("Low: {$data[3]}");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

I cannot find out what is the problem but when I open the html file and search for example for mic I won't get any result and nothing would happen.

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of your handler function.

Comment: You also misspelled the function call on your `onsubmit`  You have `showSreachResult()` and it should be `showSearchReuslt()`  -  PS - also misspelled lol

Comment: you are right about misspelled but I checked for missing } but that's not the case.

Comment: and after fixing misspells still it's not working

Comment: Edit your code in your post with whatever changes you've made

Comment: okay I did. of course not lot's of changes just fixed the misspell and also changed a line where I am defining the url

Comment: You should check that the fopen command is working on that url.  Your code could be working but $handle could be false.

Comment: OK first, remove `sleep(5);` from your PHP while you troubleshoot this.  It can only cause problems at this point.  Then take out the entire `<form ... >` line and its corresponding `</form>`.  Change your submit button from `<input type="submit" ... >` to `<input type="button" onclick="showSearchResult();" ... >`.  Place an `alert('beginning');` on the first line of `showSearchResult()` to make sure it actually fires and check your console and network request/response data in chrome dev tools to see what comes/goes/fails

Comment: Don't put `return false;` on the `onclick` - there is no default event firing that you need to worry about stopping like with `onsubmit`

Comment: Deryck thanks for your help and thank you very much for suggesting chrome dev tools (I was using Firebug). I found the problem. My mistake was using document.getElementByName("search").value==""document, where I should have used document.getElementById("search").value=="" and change the name to id in the input field as well apparently I cannot use getElementByName. Anyway you were very helpful thank you.